# How to check if several tables are locked?

Tags: mysql

I would like to check if several tables are locked or not. I tried to do it this way:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE (Table LIKE 'table_name' OR Table LIKE 'table2_name') AND In_use > 0
```

But i'm getting error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'Table LIKE 'table_name' OR Table LIKE 'table2_name') AND In_use > 0' at line 1
```

I checked that this one works fine:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE In_use > 0 LIKE "table_name"
```

but i need to check it for several tables and i would like to do it just using one query. I use MySQL in version 5.5.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table is a reserved word try to add backtics around "Table", like this:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE (`Table` LIKE 'table_name' OR `Table` LIKE 'table2_name') 
AND In_use > 0
```

Comment: Strange, I got the same error as you when I used your SQL and mine worked. Did you get the same error again?